# Convert dd-mm-yy to javascript date object

Tags: javascript

I get a date which comes in this format: `ddmmyy`, and I need to do some validation with it.
How can I parse it to a javascript date object?

I've tried to search, and there are a lot on the `ddmmyyyy` format, but not the format I get.

EDIT: Example date: `031290` = 3.12.1990.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is how I solved it.

The answers here is right, except I wasn't happy with the way the detection of the current century worked; so I basically did this:

```
var date = new Date(year + 2000, month - 1, day);

if (date > new Date())
    date.setYear(year + 1900);
```

With this code, I can maximum validate an age of 100, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Mukul Goel in the comment below points out it can only validate dates in the future. Probably right, I haven't checked it myself.

Comment: This answer takes in assumption that the date will never be in future. Probably useful in case of birth dates. but can not be used generally.

Answer (score 2):

You could parse ddmmyyyy into a yyyy-mm-dd form and pass that to Date.parse.

```
Date.parse( "02032002".replace(/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})$/, "$3-$2-$1") );
```

Or otherwise split it up and use the Date's setters / constructor:

```
// month - 1 : in this form January is 0, December is 11
var date = new Date( year, month - 1, date );
```

Just noticed the YY vs YYYY part of the question:

```
var parts = /^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{2})$/.exec( "190304" );
var date = new Date( parts[3], parts[2]-1, parts[1] );
```

You could augment that with some code which adds a 20 or 19 depending if the year is over or below a certain threshold (like 70 : < 70 indicates 20xx and >= 70 indictaes 19xx years).

Comment: He asked for ddmmyy not ddmmyyyy

Comment: parts[0] is the whole matched string, indexes 1-3 are the groups for day, month, year.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a="221178".split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/);
var result=new Date ( parseInt(a[2],10) + 1900 , a[1]-1 , a[0] )
```

result:

```
Tue Nov 22 1978 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/uBIxoVa/4/edit)

Comment: Added an example date now; e.g. 031290 = 3.12.1990.

Comment: @RoyiNamir : how to convert myDate = '20/06/17' into '20/6/2017 00:00:00' format in javascript ?

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani You can only add the zeroz but then you'll have it as a string representation.

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani http://jsbin.com/hisuxupepi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-regex solution, you can use `new Date(year, month, date)` constructor, and simple cut strings into those parts. It's not fancy, but it clear in what it does:

```
function parse2date(str){

     var year = parseInt(str.substr(4, 2));
     var month = parseInt(str.substr(2, 2));
     var day = parseInt(str.substr(0, 2))

     return new Date(year < 20 ? 2000 + year : year, month - 1, day)

 }
```

this function assumes if 2-disgit years is below 20 - then it is meant to be in 2000s, otherwise it's in 1900s. But you can adjust the limit. Try calling it:

```
alert(parse2date('031290'));
```